# How to use the Windows File System from a Xamarin Application running on Windows

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

I have a Xamarin app that runs on Android, IOS and Windows 8.?  It is essentially a “player” to display a proprietary document format.  Formatting the documents so they look good on a small screen is a trial and error process.  Essentially: Edit; Compile; Transfer to mobile; View; repeat;

To speed up this process, I am trying to build an emulator. I am using the Windows version of the app as a base for the emulator (because if I stay in Xamarin, I don’t have to rewrite all the code for Windows Forms)

The compiler is a Windows app. After compiling I know exactly where the file is located.  When I run the emulator, it does not give me access to the Windows file system. I tried using PCLStorage Library. It stored the file here:

C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\home\30011765\AppData\Local\Packages\85930d70-750c-41a6-9b95-03faaed4159c_nh7s0b45jarrj\LocalState\ZDO\dev
I specified this part \ZDO\dev but have no idea how it selected the rest. Like why OpenSSH?

Question: Given this app is only going to run on Windows, is there a way to load a file as C:... ?

If not, is there another way for a Windows Forms App to share a file with a Xamarin Windows App?

I’ve spent several hours searching for a working example solution and have yet to find one.

Comment: “Windows app” or "Windows Store app"? Your description on the problem you met is rather ambiguous and unclear. Unless you provide more info, this question is not answerable.

Comment: Sorry. In Summary, is the UsingNativeFeatures Windows possible? This is an app that will run on Windows 7 and 8. Not a windows store app.